# Modify code in order to create a function that format my numbers into specific money_format

Tags: javascript

My goal is to create a function that will format currency to a numeric value under some conditions, my script is below. With this code I am getting to format the constant `n` as I want, my question is how do I create a function that does not depend on the constant `n`? I have tried to place it as variable without defining constant and when I do that, the console does not print because I get `n is not defined`. I hope I've explained myself well, I don't have too much experience in programming so I hope you can help me.

```
import { format } from 'd3';

const n = 72932134;

// this part make the digits count
var digits_count = n => {
    var count = 0;
    if (n >= 1) ++count;

    while (n / 10 >= 1) {
    n /= 10;
    ++count;
    }

    return count;
};

// this part defines cantNum and formatofinal
var cantNum;
var formatofinal;        
    if (digits_count(n) === 0) {
        cantNum = 0;
        formatofinal ='r';
    }
    else if (digits_count(n) === 1) {
        cantNum = 1;
        formatofinal ='s';
    } 
    else if (digits_count(n) === 2) {
        cantNum = 2;
        formatofinal ='s';
    }
    else if (digits_count(n) === 3) {
        cantNum = 3;
        formatofinal ='s';
    }
    else if (digits_count(n) === 4) {
        cantNum = 2;
        formatofinal ='s';
    }
    else if (digits_count(n) === 5) {
        cantNum = 3;
        formatofinal ='s';
    }
    else if (digits_count(n) === 6) {
        cantNum = 3;
        formatofinal ='s';
    }
    else if (digits_count(n) === 7) {
        cantNum = 2;
        formatofinal ='s';
    }
    else if (digits_count(n) === 8) {
        cantNum = 3;
        formatofinal ='s';
    }
    else if (digits_count(n) === 9) {
        cantNum = 3;
        formatofinal ='s';
    }
    else {
        cantNum = 2;
        formatofinal ='s';
    };

const simbolo = "$";
 // this part give the final format to n
const formatear = d => {
    const formato = simbolo+format(",."+ cantNum +formatofinal)(d)
        .replace('.', ',')
        .replace('G', 'B');
        return formato;
};
console.log(formatear(n));
```

Comment: I didn't understand your whole problem, but I guess this could help you: `toFixed()`  change `const formato = simbolo+format(",."+ cantNum +formatofinal)(d) ` to `const formato = simbolo + cantNum.toFixed(2)`

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. State clearly the output you desire. Your code had quite a lot of other issues as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe I dont explain myself very well. My code is actually working as I want, what i would like to do is to create a function that contains the whole code. For example, fuction(n) and returns the same format. When I comment the "const n" line of the code to create the function, it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to change the implementation here, I just changed the way your code is structured. I moved most of the stuff into functions and then you can utilize the loose coupling of functions to be called only at one place where n will be defined. Check my Snippet. Unfortunately, I can't test this because you have some imported functions.

```js
import { format } from 'd3';

var formatCurrency = (function()
{
  var cantNum;
  var formatofinal; 
  const simbolo = "$";
  const _n = 72932134;
  
  function digits_count(n) 
  {
      var count = 0;
      if (n >= 1) ++count;

      while (n / 10 >= 1) {
          n /= 10;
          ++count;
      }
      return count;
  };
  
  function processCantNumAndFormatOfinal(n){   
      if (digits_count(n) === 0) {
          cantNum = 0;
          formatofinal ='r';
      }
      else if (digits_count(n) === 1) {
          cantNum = 1;
          formatofinal ='s';
      } 
      else if (digits_count(n) === 2) {
          cantNum = 2;
          formatofinal ='s';
      }
      else if (digits_count(n) === 3) {
          cantNum = 3;
          formatofinal ='s';
      }
      else if (digits_count(n) === 4) {
          cantNum = 2;
          formatofinal ='s';
      }
      else if (digits_count(n) === 5) {
          cantNum = 3;
          formatofinal ='s';
      }
      else if (digits_count(n) === 6) {
          cantNum = 3;
          formatofinal ='s';
      }
      else if (digits_count(n) === 7) {
          cantNum = 2;
          formatofinal ='s';
      }
      else if (digits_count(n) === 8) {
          cantNum = 3;
          formatofinal ='s';
      }
      else if (digits_count(n) === 9) {
          cantNum = 3;
          formatofinal ='s';
      }
      else {
          cantNum = 2;
          formatofinal ='s';
      };
  }
  
  function formatear(d)
  {
    // Process cantNum and formatofinal here ... function call
    processCantNumAndFormatOfinal(_n);
    const formato = simbolo + format(",."+ cantNum +formatofinal)(d)
        .replace('.', ',')
        .replace('G', 'B');
        return formato;
  };
  
  return function(j)
  {
    return formatear(j);
  }
})();


console.log(formatCurrency(n));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I need. The only issue is very similar that I current have, I want to call the function and declearing the constant inside the function, using your example: formatCurrency(72932134) = $72,9. I don't want to declare the constant n in an external line. I hope this help to clarify.

Comment: The question is now unclear. So `n` is not going to change?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're trying to achieve.. I have updated my answer... So I have introduced a variable `j` which represents a number that must be converted as currency. So `n` is now hard-coded inside the self-invoking function and will be used as is all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Juan Carlos Bellido Arenas!

You may find this of value. I've been using it for years.

```js
    //
    //  add a new member function to the Number prototype to format
    //  with dollars and cents.
    //  c is the number of characters after the decimal
    //  d is the decimal (default .)
    //  t is the thousands separator (default ,)
    //  y is currency marker (default $)
    //
    Number.prototype.dolFmt = function(c, d, t, y) {
        var n = this;
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c;
        d = d === undefined ? '.' : d;
        t = t === undefined ? ',' : t;
        var s = n < 0 ? '-' : '';
        y = y === undefined ? '$' : y;
        var i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + '',
            j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
        if (c === 0) d = '';
        return y +
            s +
            (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : '') +
            i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, '$1' + t) +
            (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : '')
    };
```

You use it directly on numbers, like so:

```js
var Mon = 123.45;
console.log(`Mon is ${Mon}. Mon.dolFmt() is ${Mon.dolFmt()}`);
```